# Re-order text on each line in a file, and ultimately convert into XML

Tags: text-processing, scripting, xml

I'm processing a log file and I need reorder each line (not sort). The log file looks like this:

```
11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM lat = 41.858657; lon = -91.345142
11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM lat = 42.864653; lon = -92.349914
11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM lat = 43.874808; lon = -93.350364
11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM lat = 44.885047; lon = -94.350058
11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM lat = 45.895078; lon = -95.349920
11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM lat = 46.905178; lon = -96.349837
11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM lat = 47.910303; lon = -97.350606
```

and I want to move the date/time to the end of each line:

```
lat = 41.858657; lon = -91.345142 11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM
lat = 42.864653; lon = -92.349914 11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM
lat = 43.874808; lon = -93.350364 11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM
lat = 44.885047; lon = -94.350058 11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM
lat = 45.895078; lon = -95.349920 11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM
lat = 46.905178; lon = -96.349837 11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM
lat = 47.910303; lon = -97.350606 11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM
```

`sed`? `awk`? how?

Bonus question: my end goal is to turn this into gpx/xml, and it's probably just as easy to add the intermediate text as each line is processed, so that the out looks like this:

```xml
<wpt lat="41.858657" lon="-91.345142">
    <time>11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat"="42.864653" lon="-92.349914">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat"="43.874808" lon="-93.350364">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat"="44.885047" lon="-94.350058">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat"="45.895078" lon="-95.349920">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat"="46.905178" lon="-96.349837">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat"="47.910303" lon="-97.350606">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM</time>
</wpt>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using awk :

```
 awk '{print $4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$1,$2,$3}' log_file
```

you can do it directly from you log file like this:

```
awk '{printf("<wpt %s%s\"%s\" %s%s\"%s\">\n<time>%s %s %s</time>\n</wpt>\n",$4,$5,substr($6,0,length($6)),$7,$8,$9,$1,$2,$3)}' log_file
```

output:

```
<wpt lat="41.858657" lon="-91.345142">
<time>11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM</time>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="42.864653" lon="-92.349914">
<time>11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM</time>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="43.874808" lon="-93.350364">
<time>11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM</time>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="44.885047" lon="-94.350058">
<time>11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM</time>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="45.895078" lon="-95.349920">
<time>11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM</time>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="46.905178" lon="-96.349837">
<time>11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM</time>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="47.910303" lon="-97.350606">
<time>11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM</time>
</wpt>
```

Comment: @Robert Altman check the for your bonus question

Comment: Well answered. One tweak is to replace substr($6,0,length($6)) with substr($6,0,length($6 - 1)) to drop the semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
perl -lane 'print "@F[2..$#F] $F[0] $F[1]"' log_file
```

to flip the log lines.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about perl's `-l` and `-a`.  Very handy, and `-lane` is easy to remember.

Comment: The code above appears to only move the date to the end of the line. To move the time to the end of the line as well, you need to do `perl -lane 'print "@F[3..$#F] @F[0..2]"'` .

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '   s/ *[=;]"* */="/g;s//" /2         #first sub-out spaces; for "
        s|\(.*M\) \(.*\)|\                #then do the replace
<wpt \2">\
        <time>\1</time>\
</wpt>|
' <<\INPUT
11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM lat = 41.858657; lon = -91.345142
11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM lat = 42.864653; lon = -92.349914
11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM lat = 43.874808; lon = -93.350364
11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM lat = 44.885047; lon = -94.350058
11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM lat = 45.895078; lon = -95.349920
11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM lat = 46.905178; lon = -96.349837
11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM lat = 47.910303; lon = -97.350606
INPUT
```

This is what I came up with. It's fairly simple in `sed`. I use literal characters here because it is easier for me to read and because not all `sed`'s will handle backslash escapes in the right hand substitution field. If yours does, then feel free. Anyway, definitely those inline comments will muck up any `sed` so do remove those before testing.

#### OUTPUT

```
<wpt lat="41.858657" lon="-91.345142">
        <time>11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat="42.864653" lon="-92.349914">
        <time>11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat="43.874808" lon="-93.350364">
        <time>11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat="44.885047" lon="-94.350058">
        <time>11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat="45.895078" lon="-95.349920">
        <time>11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat="46.905178" lon="-96.349837">
        <time>11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM</time>
</wpt>

<wpt lat="47.910303" lon="-97.350606">
        <time>11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM</time>
</wpt>
```

Answer (score 1):

the first part of your rearrangement can be done pretty easily, as long as the composition of the data is the same and doesn't change.

```
cat myfile | while read line
do
  latlong=$(echo ${line} | cut -d " " -f 4-)
  datetime=$(echo ${line} | cut -d " " -f 1-3)
  echo ${latlong}" "${datetime} >> mynewlyformattedfile
done
```

this can be done more elaborately on one line, using sed and/or awk I am sure, but I tried to do it this way to show what's happening at what point.

by using the `cut` command, you can extract any portion of a line and echo it with any prefix/suffix to create your xml file pretty easily in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Same for `sed`

```
sed -E 's&(.*M)( .*);( .*)$&<wpt\2\3>\n\t<time>\1</time>\n</wpt>&;
        $!G;
        s& = ([-.0-9]+)&="\1"&g' log.file
```

Or put it in the script-file

```
#!/bin/sed -Ef
s|(.*M)( .*);( .*)$|<wpt\2\3>\n\t<time>\1</time>\n</wpt>|
$!G
s| = ([-.0-9]+)|="\1"|g
```

And use it

```
sed -Ef script.file log.file
```

or if have made it executable by `chmod +x ./script.file` just

```
./script.file log.file
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Converting the data to `;`-delimited CSV by replacing the `lat =` and `lon =` appropriately.  Also output a simple header.

   ```bsh
   echo 'time;@lat;@lon'
   sed -e 's/;\{0,1\}[[:blank:]]... = /;/g' file
   ```

   This removes an optional semi-colon, three characters, and an equal sign surrounded by a space on either side, and replaces all this by a semi colon.  The substitution is repeated until nothing more matches (it will substitute twice on each line).

   The output will look like this:

   ```
   time;@lat;@lon
   11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM;41.858657;-91.345142
   11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM;42.864653;-92.349914
   11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM;43.874808;-93.350364
   11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM;44.885047;-94.350058
   11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM;45.895078;-95.349920
   11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM;46.905178;-96.349837
   11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM;47.910303;-97.350606
   ```
2. Take this and let `csvjson` from `csvkit` convert this into JSON:

   ```bsh
   csvjson -d ';'
   ```

   The output from this will be the equivalent of

   ```json
   [
   {"time":"11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM","@lat":41.858657,"@lon":-91.345142},
   {"time":"11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM","@lat":42.864653,"@lon":-92.349914},
   {"time":"11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM","@lat":43.874808,"@lon":-93.350364},
   {"time":"11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM","@lat":44.885047,"@lon":-94.350058},
   {"time":"11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM","@lat":45.895078,"@lon":-95.34992},
   {"time":"11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM","@lat":46.905178,"@lon":-96.349837},
   {"time":"11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM","@lat":47.910303,"@lon":-97.350606}
   ]
   ```
3. Use `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ to trans-code this straight into XML.  This is where the keys prefixed by with `@` will be treated as attributes, while other keys will be treated as node names.

   ```bsh
   yq --xml-root=wpt -x .
   ```

   Result:

   ```xml
   <wpt lat="41.858657" lon="-91.345142">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM</time>
   </wpt><wpt lat="42.864653" lon="-92.349914">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM</time>
   </wpt><wpt lat="43.874808" lon="-93.350364">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM</time>
   </wpt><wpt lat="44.885047" lon="-94.350058">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM</time>
   </wpt><wpt lat="45.895078" lon="-95.34992">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM</time>
   </wpt><wpt lat="46.905178" lon="-96.349837">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM</time>
   </wpt><wpt lat="47.910303" lon="-97.350606">
     <time>11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM</time>
   </wpt>
   ```

Summary:

```bsh
{
    echo 'time;@lat;@lon'
    sed -e 's/;\{0,1\}[[:blank:]]... = /;/g' file
} |
csvjson -d ';' |
yq --xml-root=wpt -x .
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

```
$ raku -e 'my @reordered = do for lines() {(.words[3..*],.words[0..2])}; .put for @reordered;' input.txt
lat = 41.858657; lon = -91.345142 11-06-2014 - 10:49:06PM
lat = 42.864653; lon = -92.349914 11-06-2014 - 10:49:49PM
lat = 43.874808; lon = -93.350364 11-06-2014 - 10:50:35PM
lat = 44.885047; lon = -94.350058 11-06-2014 - 10:51:21PM
lat = 45.895078; lon = -95.349920 11-06-2014 - 10:52:08PM
lat = 46.905178; lon = -96.349837 11-06-2014 - 10:53:30PM
lat = 47.910303; lon = -97.350606 11-06-2014 - 10:54:50PM
```

*[...still working on the XML-output solution... ].*